# Bootstrap collapse ok but hamburger menu not showing the items

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

Following the tutorial on YelpCamp. Also I read post on this site but still I can't figure out why the items of the menu did'nt show up when the hamburger menu is displayed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Imperial Fleet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css">
  </head>

  <body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Imperial Fleet</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="/ships">Ships</a></li>
              <li><a href="/fleets">Fleets</a></li>
              <li><a href="/bases">Bases</a></li>

              <% if(!currentUser){ %>
                  <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/register">Sign up</a></li>
                <% } else { %>
                  <li><a href="#">Signed in as: <%= currentUser.username %></a></li>
                  <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
                <% } %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <% if (error && error.length > 0 ) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
      <%= error %>
    </div>
  <% } %>

  <% if (success && success.length > 0 ) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
      <%= success %>
    </div>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

The last `<div class="container">`

is only for displaying flash-connect messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was on this line:

Mistake:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
```

Solution:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

I forgot the id tag.

Answer (score 1):

Have you included js plugins  for this on your page ?

Following the [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#navbar) :

> Requires JavaScript plugin
>
> If JavaScript is disabled and the viewport is narrow enough that the
>   navbar collapses, it will be impossible to expand the navbar and view
>   the content within the **.navbar-collapse**.
>
> The responsive navbar requires the [collapse plugin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#collapse) to be included in
>   your version of Bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks I solved the trouble, I was forgetting the data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"  tag. Thanks anyway